# Absence of backslash in the hardcoded variable output , but present in file output

Tags: c++, file, backslash

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main () 
{
string strFile = "";
ifstream myfile ("data.doc");

string strPgm  = "{ \"c\" : { \"p1\": \"v1\", \"p2\":\"v2\" } }";
cout << "\n string from program is : " << strPgm <<"\n"; 
if (myfile.is_open())
{
string line;
while ( getline (myfile,line) )
{
  strFile = strFile+line;
}
myfile.close();
cout <<"\n string from file is  : " << strFile <<"\n";
}

else cout << "Unable to open file"; 
return 0;
}
```

In my code , backslash is coming in the file output , but it is absent in the output of hard coded variable value in the program.I am not sure , if I am missing something.

---

The contents of the file data.doc is same as in the variable strPgm,
cat data.doc ,

```
"{ \"c\" : { \"p1\": \"v1\", \"p2\": \"v2\" } }"
```

But I am getting the output as ,

string from program is :

```
{ "c" : { "p1": "v1", "p2": "v2" } }
```

string from file is  :

```
"{ \"c\" : { \"p1\": \"v1\", \"p2\": \"v2\" } }"
```

Why is this so ? Both are same strings . Because of this, problem is happening while converting strFile in jsonFormat and parsing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the *compiler* which handles escapes and backslashes in constant string literals. So if you have a string like `"Hello\nWorld"` in your source code it is the compiler that converts `\n` to a newline. If you have a file containing backslashes, those are not processed but read as-is.

Answer (score 2):

You've misunderstood what this line does:

```
string strPgm  = "{ \"c\" : { \"p1\": \"v1\", \"p2\":\"v2\" } }";
```

It does not create a string that has backslashes in it. The backslashes are for *escaping* the double-quotes so that the entire line is considered part of your string to store, instead of stopping at the `c`.

If you really want to write actual backslashes into a string literal, you'll have to write them like this:

```
string strPgm  = "{ \\\"c\\\" : { \\\"p1\\\": \\\"v1\\\", ...
```

i.e. first the backslash, with an escape to make it an actual backslash (lol):

```
\\
```

and then the escaped double-quote:

```
\"
```

Though it seems really unlikely that you'd want to store escaped JSON.

Comment: I know what the strPgm does.But,  I didn't understand why the outputs are different when same string is stored in a file.I don't want to write backslashes.In fact , my requirement is that while copying or storing  the contents of the file to a variable, and then printing it , it should not contain any backslashes.While I am hard coding, backslash is getting escaped.But while I am reading from the file, the same thing is not happening.

Comment: The file already contain the backslash,because the file contains the output of a python program. And I am not able find a way to store the json into a file without backslash.

Comment: @Busy: I don't understand your concern. I've explained what your C++ string is. You've said that your file contains something else. Well, then, that's why they're different. Are you _really_ asking how to unescape a string read from a file? Because your question doesn't say that! I've also shown you how to produce a C++ string with literal backslashes included, in case you want that.

Comment: My requirement is that , I want to escape backslash while I am reading from a file.The file contains the same string like that is stored in strPgm.

Comment: @BusyTraveller: _"The file contains the same string like that is stored in strPgm"_ No, it doesn't. You told us that, and I've explained why.

Comment: Sorry to correct you , I am pasting the following from the original post , The contents of the file data.doc is same as in the variable strPgm, cat data.doc ,

"{ \"c\" : { \"p1\": \"v1\", \"p2\": \"v2\" } }"

Comment: @BusyTraveller: Sorry to correct you, I am pasting the following from the original post. _«string from program is : `{ "c" : { "p1": "v1", "p2": "v2" } }`»_ How are they the same? I thought you were asking why they are not the same. Saying they are the same then showing that they're not is ... very confusing. At this point I have no idea what your question is.